# Update row if exists

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP script I save data to database (hash, sala).
I want to update hash if sala is exists (update hash in same row).

How to change in my script?

```
$sala = $_POST['sala'];

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else{
    echo "Polaczono";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO instructions (hash, sala)
VALUES ('$newfilename', '$sala')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Dane dodano prawidłowo";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: I've copied the relevant code to into the question.   Please understand it is more difficult for people to visit an external resource to get your code, and further, **when** that link breaks (not if, *when*), this question will have no value to future visitors.

Comment: `$newfilename` is defined where/how? seems file-related.

Comment: Your code is wide open to [SQL Injection attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax to update the value if key already exists, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO instructions (hash, sala) VALUES("A", "B") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
hash = "C";
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) is the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query instead:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO instructions (hash, sala)
VALUES ('$newfilename', '$sala')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hash='$newfilename'";
```

Also you need to create **UNIQUE KEY** on column `sala`.
And don't forget about SQL injection attack as you been told before.